# Insert new data into specified node in XML file

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to insert a new element inside the `<channel>` tag using vb code. My code adds the new items *after* `<channel>` and `<rss>` end tags end.

I have tried this :

```
document.Root.Elements.First().Add(root)
```

but it didn't work.

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>

    </channel>
</rss>
```

This is my code :

```
FilePath = "h:\root\home\ka-001\www\site1\xmlfile1.xml"
Dim document As XDocument = New XDocument()

If File.Exists(FilePath) Then
        document = XDocument.Load(FilePath)
Else
        Label1.Text = "! file dosn't exist"
End If

If FileUpload1.HasFile = True Then
        If FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength <= size Then
            Dim strPath As String
            strPath = "~/files/" & FileUpload1.FileName
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(strPath))
        End If
    End If

    attac1 = FileUpload1.FileName

    Dim root As XElement = New XElement("item")
    Dim title As XElement = New XElement("title", New XCData(TextBox3.Text))
    Dim link As XElement = New XElement("link", TextBox6.Text)

    root.Add(title, link)
    document.Root.Add(root)
    document.Save(FilePath)
    Label1.Text = "! done"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add the new element to the *root* (that's the `<rss>` element) - but to the `<channel>` sub-element - so you need to grab that one first - like this (code in C# - should be pretty easy to convert to VB.NET) :

```
var channelNode = document.Root.Descendants("channel").FirstOrDefault();
```

Then, once you have that channel node, you can add the new element to it - I am assuming you want to add one element `<item>` with two sub-elements - correct?

This can be accomplished with this code:

```
// create new <item> element
XElement item = new XElement("item");

// add sub-element <title> to <item>
item.Add(new XElement("title", new XCData(TextBox3.Text)));

// add sub-element <link> to <item>
item.Add(new XElement("link", TextBox6.Text));

// and now add the <item> element inside the <channel> element
channelNode.Add(item);
```